# Calculate the average rating in a table using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called `company_reviews` where i store reviews and a rating number (1-5) submitted by a user. I need to calculate the average between many reviews and output the total with only one decimal (for example 2.5, 3.5, 2.1, 5.1 etc.) In other woords, I need to calculate the total of every `company_reviews_rating` related to and where `company_reviews_company_id` is `id = x`.

**Table structure**

```
+--------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
| company_reviews_id | company_reviews_company_id | company_reviews_rating |
+--------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
|                  1 |                          1 |                      1 |
|                  2 |                          1 |                      5 |
|                  3 |                          1 |                      4 |
|                  4 |                          1 |                      4 |
|                  5 |                          1 |                      3 |
|                  6 |                          1 |                      2 |
+--------------------+----------------------------+------------------------+
```

This is what I've come up with so far, but i'm stuck from here

```
public function count_total_rating($id = NULL) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('company_reviews_company_id', $id);
    $this->db->from('company_reviews');
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

**How would one do that in a Codeigniter model?**

Comment: From the [manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html): $this->db->select_avg();

Comment: @ThomasGhesquiere Codeigniter doc's now here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Comment: use AVG(column_name) in the place of *

Answer (score 0):

```
public function count_total_rating($id = NULL) {
    $this->db->select('AVG(company_reviews_rating) as average');
    $this->db->where('company_reviews_company_id', $id);
    $this->db->from('company_reviews');
    $query = $this->db->get();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function getAveRating(company_reviews_company_id){ 
        $where=array(
             "company_reviews_company_id"=>company_reviews_company_id
             );
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->select_avg('company_reviews_rating');
        $query = $this->db->get('company_reviews')->first_row('array');
        return round($query['company_reviews_rating'], 2);
}
```

I hope this helps :D